# No provider for Http StaticInjectorError

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I am trying to pull the data from my api, and populate it in my ionic app, but it is crashing when I enter the page the data should be populated on.  Below are my two .ts files:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { NavController, LoadingController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { RestService } from '../../providers/rest-service/rest-service';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-all-patients',
  templateUrl: 'all-patients.html',
  providers: [RestService]
})
export class AllPatientsPage {
  data: any;
  loading: any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public restService: RestService, public loadingCtrl: LoadingController) {

    this.loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
      content: `
        <ion-spinner></ion-spinner>`
    });
    this.getdata();
  }

  getdata() {
    this.loading.present();
    this.restService.getJsonData().subscribe(
      result => {
        this.data=result.data.children;
        console.log("Success: " + this.data);
      },
      err => {
        console.error("Error : " + err);
      },
      () => {
        this.loading.dismiss();
        console.log('getData completed');
     }
   );
 }
}
```

and the other file:

```
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

/*
  Generated class for the RestServiceProvider provider.

  See https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection for more info on providers
  and Angular DI.
*/

@Injectable()
export class RestService {

  constructor(public http: Http) {
    console.log('Hello RestServiceProvider Provider');
  }

  getJsonData() {
    // return Promise.resolve(this.data);

     return this.http.get('url').map(res => res.json());
   }

}
```

I have tried using the HttpModule as well, but it is a fatal error. The error is as shows:

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError[Http]: 
  StaticInjectorError[Http]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for Http!
Error: StaticInjectorError[Http]: 
  StaticInjectorError[Http]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for Http!
    at _NullInjector.get (http://lndapp.wpi.edu:8100/build/vendor.js:1276:19)
```

I am unsure why there is a no provider error, as this is the provider created through ionic framework

Answer (score 139, accepted):

In order to use Http in your app you will need to add the HttpModule to your app.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
...
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    IonicStorageModule.forRoot()
  ]
```

**EDIT**

As mentioned in the comment below, **`HttpModule`** is **`deprecated`** now, use **`import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http'`**; Make sure **`HttpClientModule`** in your **`imports:[]`** array

Comment: I have added this to the app.module.ts, but now get the error: `Cannot find name 'IonicStorageModule'.`

Comment: you have to do the import import { IonicStorageModule } from '@ionic/storage'; . above is just a samplem, you can remove it if you dont want

Comment: I did have that in there, but when I remove it, it works.  Thanks!

Comment: HttpModule seems to be deprecated now, use 
`import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';` instead and for sure name `HttpClientModule` in your imports:[] array.

Comment: Be sure to also include your service in the list of [providers] as shown in answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/52791929/2023941 below, and restart the compiler.

Comment: I tried replacing HttpModule with HttpClientModule, but for my app it still needed both of them for backward compatibility

Comment: brilliant answer

Answer (score 44):

#### Update: Angular v6+

**For Apps converted from older versions (Angular v2 - v5): HttpModule is now deprecated and you need to replace it with HttpClientModule or else you will get the error too.**

1. In your **app.module.ts** replace `import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';` with the new HttpClientModule `import { HttpClientModule} from "@angular/common/http";` **Note: Be sure to then update the modules `imports[]` array by removing the old `HttpModule` and replacing it with the new `HttpClientModule`.**
2. In any of your services that used HttpModule replace
   `import { Http } from '@angular/http';` with the new HttpClient `import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';`
3. Update how you handle your Http response. For example - If you have code that looks like this

   `http.get('people.json').subscribe((res:Response) => this.people = res.json());`

The above code example will result in an error. We no longer need to parse the response, because it already comes back as JSON in the config object.

> The subscription callback copies the data fields into the component's config object, which is data-bound in the component template for display.

For more information please see the -
[Angular HttpClientModule - Official Documentation](https://angular.io/guide/http)

Comment: getting error `NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpClient!`

Answer (score 8):

You would need also to import the `HttpClientModule` from Angular `'@angular/common/http'` into your main AppModule for making HTTP requests.

**app.module.ts**

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ServiceService } from '../../../services/service.service';

@NgModule({
   imports: [
       HttpClientModule
   ],
   providers: [
       ServiceService
   ]
})
export class AppModule {...}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add these two file in your `app.module.ts`

```
import { FileTransfer } from '@ionic-native/file-transfer';
import { File } from '@ionic-native/file';
```

after that declare these to in provider..

```
providers: [
    Api,
    Items,
    User,
    Camera,
    File,
    FileTransfer];
```

This is work for me.

Comment: Could you please mark blocks of code as such by selecting them and clicking the ``{}`` icon in the editing toolbar? Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

I am on an angular project that (unfortunately) uses source code inclusion via `tsconfig.json` to connect different collections of code.  I came across a similar `StaticInjector` error for a service (e.g.`RestService` in the top example) and I was able to fix it by listing the service dependencies in the `deps` array when providing the affected service in the module, for example:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { RestService } from 'mylib/src/rest/rest.service';
...
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
    HttpModule,
    ...
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: RestService,
      useClass: RestService,
      deps: [HttpClient] /* the injected services in the constructor for RestService */
    },
  ]
  ...
```

Comment: good one ! may you please explain "source code inclusion via tsconfig.json" ??

Answer (score 1):

In ionic 4.6 I use the following technique and it works. I am adding this answer so that if anybody is facing similar issues in newer ionic version app, it may help them.

i) Open app.module.ts and add the following code block to import HttpModule and HttpClientModule

```
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import {   HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
```

ii) In @NgModule import sections add below lines:

```
HttpModule,
HttpClientModule,
```

So, in my case @NgModule, looks like this:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent ],
  entryComponents: [ ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(),
    AppRoutingModule, 
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

That's it!

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to fix the issue for about an hour and just deiced to **restart** the server. Only to see the issue is fixed.

If you make changes to APP module and the issue remains the same, **stop the server and try running the serve command again.**

*Using ionic 4 with angular 7*