# ionic-native/http emit error “NullInjectorError: No provider for HTTP!”

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm using *ionic 3.2* and angular, for install `HTTP` (https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/http/) I use this commands:

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-advanced-http
npm install --save @ionic-native/http
```

In script `autenticar.ts` I added the `import { HTTP } from '@ionic-native/http';` like this:

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { HTTP } from '@ionic-native/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-autenticar',
  templateUrl: 'autenticar.html'
})
export class AutenticarPage {

  @ViewChild('username') username;
  @ViewChild('password') password;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public http: HTTP) {
    console.log(http)
  }

...
```

After reload app I get this error:

> ```
> Runtime Error
> Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)
> [AutenticarPage -> HTTP]: StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[AutenticarPage -> HTTP]:
> NullInjectorError: No provider for HTTP!
> Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[AutenticarPage -> HTTP]:
> StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[AutenticarPage -> HTTP]:
> NullInjectorError: No provider for HTTP! at _NullInjector.get
> (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:1376:19) at resolveToken
> (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:1674:24) at tryResolveToken
> (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:1616:16) at StaticInjector.get
> (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:1484:20) at resolveToken
> (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:1674:24) at tryResolveToken
> (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:1616:16) at StaticInjector.get
> (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:1484:20) at resolveNgModuleDep
> (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:11228:25) at NgModuleRef_.get
> (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:12461:16) at resolveDep
> (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:12951:45)
> ```

I try this [**answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47492777/1518921), says I have to add the `app.module.ts` this `import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';`, like this:

```
import { NgModule, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { IonicApp, IonicModule, IonicErrorHandler } from 'ionic-angular';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { MyApp } from './app.component';

....

  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],

...
```

But still the same error.

Comment: I think you need to add `HTTP` in providers also in app.module.ts

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to add HTTP in providers

app.module.ts

```
...

import { HTTP } from '@ionic-native/http';

...

@NgModule({
  ...

  providers: [
    ...
    HTTP
    ...
  ]
  ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: it looks like it worked, but it looks like HTTP does not work in the browser, just on devices. This is correct?

Comment: Yes some of ionic native modules will work only in device not on browser.

Comment: If you want to work on browser and device also so you need to use `@angular/http` not through cordova.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! +1 :)

Comment: I usually create a helper class that utilizes both native and angular HTTP. When the platform detected is Cordova, the helper class uses the native HTTP module. If not, then Angular HTTP is used accordingly.

Comment: @Earlee What is different between native HTTP module vs Angular HTTP module ? I always use angular HTTP module in ionic apps.

Comment: They wrote it in their documentation. "Background threading - all requests are done in a background thread and SSL Pinning" https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/http/

Comment: In Ionic 4 use `import {HTTP} from '@ionic-native/http/ngx';`

Answer (score 4):

You need to add HTTP under **[`providers`](http://%20https://github.com/monkeyDledger/uppayDemo/blob/b4996f9e2bcbd4781c7c9ed7f6ebc674cdfa8c39/src/app/app.module.ts#L56)**

```
providers: [
    HTTP
]
```

Comment: So the [*documentation*](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/http/) is incorrect? I tried your sugestion, but I get another error: `Can't resolve all parameters for AutenticarPage: ([object Object], ?).` - screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSn24.png

Comment: it looks like it worked, but it looks like HTTP does not work in the browser, just on devices. This is correct?

Comment: thanks 1+ :) - Note: I accepted the other answer because he answered first.