# Resolver not works - angular

Tags: angular, routes, angular5, resolve

state.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import {Http} from "@angular/http";
import {Resolve, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot} from "@angular/router";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/delay';
@Injectable()
export class StateOptions implements Resolve<Observable<string>> {

   constructor(private http:Http) {
}

resolve() {
    return Observable.of('Hello Alligator!').delay(2000);
  }
}
```

routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {StateOptions} from './state.service';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component:AppComponent,
    resolve: { message: StateOptions }    
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: [StateOptions]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
.....
import { StateOptions } from './state.service'



@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    HomeComponent,
    AppComponent,  
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    StateOptions


  ],
  exports: [

  ],
  providers: [StateOptions],
  bootstrap: [HomeComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I am trying to use resolver in my project . The above shown is the configuration. I am getting error on console, nothing shows in browser..it was working before adding resolver..i think problem is with the resolver configuration
this is the error i am facing..appreciate any help

```
 Unexpected value 'StateOptions' imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `stateOptions` from `imports` array. Its a service and not a module. Only modules are supposed to be imported.

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
   //StateOptions
  ],
```

Comment: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[StateOptions -> Http]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[StateOptions -> Http]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for Http!
_NullInjector.prototype.get@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:1219:19
resolveToken@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:1517:17
tryResolveToken@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular.....

Comment: If you google your error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47492475/no-provider-for-http-staticinjectorerror. In your service you are using `Http` but you have imported `HttpClientModule`. Use `HttpClient` class instead of `Http`.